# Encode currency symbol from SQL DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, currency

I have a situation where a DB has been setup on a SQL server and one of the fields has been setup incorrectly - meaning It's supposed to show "£100;00 INSTANT LOTTO" but the column wasn't setup properly and instead shows "?100;00 INSTANT LOTTO"

It's doubtful we can change the column now as we can't risk data loss.

Anyone have any ideas how I can change this in the code; c#, or the front end?

Comment: If the column was set up as varchar instead of nvarchar, you've likely already lost data. You should fix the column and then look at writing an update script to fix the data.

Comment: The question is a bit broad, since there are lots of options, but I think you should re-consider the data fix, that's a 1 time fix, vs carrying the debt of the bad data into potentially multiple other code locations.

Comment: Should it ideally have been setup as a numeric column with possible text around it in the presentation layer? Or is the text range fairly broad in that this is just one example of text before and after the numeric value? If it needs to stay as text then you should use `NVarchar`, converting from `varchar` to `nvarchar` you will not have loss of data.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean there's no likely, he's definitely lost data as his characters are all question marks. Leaving the database in the current state is definitely the worst option. Fixing now and having clean data going forward is good. And if the column is not properly configured there *is no other fix* until it can accept the data type. Unless OP plans on converting ? into £ in the front end. The good news is that going to a different char format will most likely not cause problems with data and only increase space usage.

Comment: @JacobH Yea, my original comment omitted the likely, but then I remembered https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8067/if-only-the-sith-deal-in-absolutes-why-does-obi-wan-say-it-that-way